# how to write ruby prime numbers between 100 and 120 code?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am a beginner to ruby and rspec, how ever I like to learn ruby and trying to test through rspec framework I am not sure what I am doing is right if any please suggest.

I wrote prime number program in ruby. While executing ruby I am getting an syntax error I specified below. I also like to know how to use this prime numbers in rspec framework.

**Error:**

```
$ruby main.rb
main.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
def find_prime(100,120)
              ^
main.rb:3: warning: possibly useless use of a literal in void context
```

**PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 100 and 120:**

```
def find_prime(100,120)
  prime = []
while (100 <= 120)
prime_flag = true
i = 2
while (i <= 100/2)
  if 100%i == 0
    prime_flag = false
    break
  end
  i +=1
end
if prime_flag
  prime << 100
end
100+=1
end
prime
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use literal numbers, such as `100` or `120`, as variable names. It confuses the Ruby interpreter. Ruby does not understand your `100` as being "the number I start with and want to change", it just always uses the exact value 100.

To start with, change your definition to something with variable names in it:

```
def find_prime( from_num, to_num )
```

and then alter other lines of code to match. You will then need to call this function at the end, with the values that you want to use:

```
find_prime( 100, 120 )
```

There may be other issues with your code too, but I will let you figure those out (or you can ask another question). The above explains the error message Ruby is giving for the code in the question.

Comment: Thank u Neil. Let me change the variable names, will call the function at the end and will execute. Please update if there is any other issue with the code. Also suggest me how to use this code on rspec framework to test.

Comment: @Arun: Please ask a new question, if this answers your original one. Don't edit it to be a new and extended question. Someone else might be best to answer your questions about rspec - you should at least *start* to write a test for your function to help someone answering understand where you are stuck. If you have done nothing at all yet with rpsec, take a look at an introduction, like http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-rspec

Comment: Sure Neil. Let me check the blog and also I am learning it through http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/1

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
def prime?(n)
  [*2..n/2].none?{|i|(n % i).zero?} ? true : false
end

for i in 100..120
  print i if prime?(i)
end
```

Comment: Could you help me to use the same code on rspec framework to test or an outline to do it.